# Getting the return type of resolved promise?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a variable with some default values, that is an extended interface of the resolved return type from a promise. My function would be something like:

```
function getAge(): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(42)
  })
}
```

My variable with default values would be:

```
let user: { name: string, age: number } = { name: "", age: 0 }
```

I've tried using the ReturnType<>, however I can only seem to get the return type `Promise<number>`, when I just want number returned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to extract the value type of a promise:

```
function getAge(): Promise<{ name: string, age: number }> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve({ name: "", age: 42 })
  })
}

type UnboxPromise<T extends Promise<any>> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U: never;

let user: UnboxPromise<ReturnType<typeof getAge>> = { name: "", age: 0 }
```

Read more about conditional types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types)

Comment: This is great. Can I somehow add my own properties to the type being returned? Let's say I want to return a type with the infered type along with some other keys. Something like `UnboxPromise<T extends Promise<any>, I> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? { ...U, ...I }: never;`

Comment: @StephanOlsen that is a case for intersection types: `type UnboxPromise<T extends Promise<any>, I> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U & I : never`

Comment: Silly me, should have tried that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18):

### Update in Typescript 4.5

You can use new [Awaited](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) type

for example:

```
let bar: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof foo>>
```

This basically works the same as the `UnboxPromise` example above, but Awaited can unwrap Promise's recursively.

### Old Answer

I liked the answer above (`UnboxPromise` example).

Alternatively, you can define a type similar to ReturnType, only with the return value as a promise.

```
type ReturnPromiseType<T extends (...args: any) => Promise<any>> = T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer R> ? R : any;
```

Example:

```
// Our declared type
type ReturnPromiseType<T extends (...args: any) => Promise<any>> = T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer R> ? R : any;

// Let's imagine that we do not have direct access to this type (a typical case when using external libraries)
interface Foo {
    a: string
}

// Here we already have access to the function, but we still don't have access to the return type.
function foo(): Promise<Foo> {
    return Promise.resolve({
        a: "abc"
    })
}

(async () => {
    let bar: ReturnPromiseType<typeof foo> // returns our interface/type Foo
    let baz: any // any by default

    bar = await foo();
    baz = await foo();

    // typeof bar
    // in IDE shows - let bar: Foo
    // typeof bar.a
    // in IDE shows - (property) Foo.a: string
    
    //typeof baz
    // in IDE shows - any
    //typeof baz.a
    // in IDE shows - any
})();
```

[in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkFcCdQEwKYGMA2BDaC6gC4E8AHBAWACh8jQAlBHGAOwAVoB7AWwEsBnBAFUIQAeXqAQAPHAnpwuoABQA6JRgDmXAFyg09PAEpQAXgB8oZu25DteIyYOgR4ydNmLl0NZqv7jp1px6CHPQAZgiwVCYA-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-kBFYRGg+H0MrvnzfL8F6gIus4xoOD7Ls+267vuoBHlYYHXhBJZ3lBT6brBb4IVoOj-LovZkEAA)